# Trying to unstyle an a tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to remove the neon glow of the  tags in my **navigation slide**. The problem is that those  tag also applies to the  tags for other elements on my html page that I actually want to keep neon. Is there a way I can still style those elements  while unstyling the  tags in my navigation slide? I'm 99% sure its the class -     **#navigation ul li a {** that I am trying to make it look normal, but it's not working at all. I have tried text-decoration: none, I've tried renaming it as well. So far nothing is working. Any advise would be great. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Responsive Portfolio Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <section class="banner" id="sec">
      <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
        <div id="toggle" onclick="toggle()"></div>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Hello World,<br />I'm <span>Chaz Carothers </span></h2>
        <p>
          A front-end developer who focuses on writing clean code while
          producing beautiful and user-friendly applications.
        </p>
        <br />
        <button>
          <a
            href="https://chaz-carothers.netlify.app"
            class="button"
            style="margin-top: 0"
            >Tree.Link</a
          >
        </button>
      </div>

      <ul class="sci">
        <li>
          <a href="https://github.com/Baobab-Prince"
            ><img src="img/git.png"
          /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/BaobabPrince"
            ><img src="img/twitter.png"
          /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/chaz-carothers-169117194/"
            ><img src="img/linkedin.png"
          /></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html style-decoration: none">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About/index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Projects/index.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggle() {
        var sec = document.getElementById('sec');
        var nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
        sec.classList.toggle('active');
        nav.classList.toggle('active');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

-------------------------------CSS-------------------------------

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

header .logo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

header #toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header #toggle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}

header #toggle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}

.banner.active #toggle:before {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.banner.active #toggle:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(inline_image_preview.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.banner.active {
  transform: translate(-400px);
}

.banner .content {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.banner .content h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.banner .content h2 span {
  color: #87ceeb;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.banner .content p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.banner .content a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

button {
  --glow-color: rgb(217, 176, 255);
  --glow-spread-color: rgba(191, 123, 255, 0.781);
  --enhanced-glow-color: rgb(231, 206, 255);
  --btn-color: rgb(100, 61, 136);
  outline: none;
  border: 0.25em solid var(--glow-color);
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  color: var(--glow-color);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: var(--btn-color);
  border-radius: 1em;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.25em var(--glow-color), 0 0 4em 1em var(--glow-spread-color), inset 0 0 0.75em 0.25em var(--glow-color);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em var(--glow-color);
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

button::after {
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 120%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--glow-spread-color);
  filter: blur(2em);
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: perspective(1.5em) rotateX(35deg) scale(1, 0.6);
}

button:hover {
  color: var(--btn-color);
  background-color: var(--glow-color);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.25em var(--glow-color), 0 0 4em 2em var(--glow-spread-color), inset 0 0 0.75em 0.25em var(--glow-color);
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em 0.25em var(--glow-color), 0 0 2.5em 2em var(--glow-spread-color), inset 0 0 0.5em 0.25em var(--glow-color);
}

.sci {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 100px;
}

.sci li {
  list-style: none;
}

.sci li a {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.sci li a:hover {
  background: #0f2537;
}

.sci li a img {
  filter: invert(1);
  max-width: 20px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #643d88;
  z-index: 1;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#navigation.active {
  right: 0;
}

#navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navigation ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  color: #ebebeb;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
  --glow-color: rgb(217, 176, 255);
  --glow-spread-color: rgba(191, 123, 255, 0.781);
  --enhanced-glow-color: rgb(231, 206, 255);
  --btn-color: rgb(100, 61, 136);
  outline: none;
  color: var(--glow-color);
  background-color: var(--btn-color);
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.25em var(--glow-color), 0 0 4em 1em var(--glow-spread-color), inset 0 0 0.75em 0.25em var(--glow-color);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em var(--glow-color);
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--btn-color);
  background-color: var(--glow-color);
}

a.logo {
  style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  header {
    padding: 20px 50px;
  }
  .banner {
    padding: 100px 50px 150px;
  }
  .banner .content h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
  }
  .banner .content p,
  .banner .content a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .banner.active {
    transform: translate(-250px);
  }
  #navigation {
    width: 300px;
  }
  #navigation ul li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  .sci {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: initial;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .sci li a {
    margin: initial;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which link **specifically** are you trying to affect? You need to make your selector **very** specific.

Comment: can you make the snippet work?

Answer (score 1):

You neon style are applied to all `<a>`. That's why all your nav link have this style.
Change your neon style applied to your `a{}` tag to the right selector. It will resolve the issue.

```
a{ //change your selector here.
  --glow-color: rgb(217, 176, 255);
  --glow-spread-color: rgba(191, 123, 255, 0.781);
  --enhanced-glow-color: rgb(231, 206, 255);
  --btn-color: rgb(100, 61, 136);
  outline: none;
  color: var(--glow-color);

  background-color: var(--btn-color);
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.25em var(--glow-color),
    0 0 4em 1em var(--glow-spread-color),
    inset 0 0 0.75em 0.25em var(--glow-color);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em var(--glow-color);
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```